# How to hide Navigation Bar, when my wkwebview start scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift5

I am using WKWebview to show my content. When I scroll webview, I would like to hide my navbar. I use below code and nothing is happen.

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

Can someone tell me, how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add top constraint for the webView with superview, set `hidesBarsOnSwipe` to true, and then load the URL (check screenshot for reference):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways through code is you can use the scrollview delegate method to identify if webview is scrolled. And there you can use `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(isHidden, animated: true)`.
Something like this:

set scrollview delegate in viewdidload `self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self`. And then use

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview).y > 0
    {
        print("up")
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
    else
    {
        print("down")
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```